# Grails 4 WAR file confusion

Tags: java, gradle, grails

I have a Grails application that I have upgraded from 3.3.0 to 4.0.3. 
In my build.gradle file I have the following

```
war {
    archiveName 'Wolf.war'
}
```

In version 3, this would name my war file Wolf.war when running "grails war" just as expected. However, in Grails 4 this no longer works for me. I know this is related to Gradle. I have Gradle 5.1.1, and per the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html) the archiveName property is deprecated (but should still work?).

My question is, what is the proper way, in a Grails 4 app using Gradle 5 (or above?) to force the name of the war file being produced by the "grails war" command?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using the default build config, you should use `bootWar` instead of `war`.

```
bootWar {
    archiveName 'Wolf.war'
}
```

Comment: Is that what I would use if I intend to drop the war into a tomcat server?

Comment: I'm not looking for a bootable war or jar. I just want a standard war file that can be deployed to an existing tomcat server.

Comment: "Is that what I would use if I intend to drop the war into a tomcat server?" - Yes.

Comment: "I'm not looking for a bootable war or jar. I just want a standard war file that can be deployed to an existing tomcat server." - The `"boot"` part of `"bootWar"` doesn't really have anything to do with being bootable.  `bootWar` is a Gradle task provided by Spring Boot (which Grails is built on top of).  When you run `grails war`, the `bootWar` task gets run.

Comment: That does create the war file with the desired name. However, something is still amiss. After I drop the war file into tomcat, and tomcat explodes it automatically, I now see an org.springframework.boot.loader folder. I didn't have this before. I don' t know if it matters to have that or not. My bigger concern is that I no longer have an assets folder, so now I don't have any of my images and css files. I'll keep digging.

Comment: I would need to see the project but the syntax I show in the answer will configure the name of the `.war` file and I don't see any connection between that and the folder issues you are seeing.  I am sorry that I can't help.  Best of luck!

Comment: If you think it is a bug in our build stuff, please file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues with a reproducible example and we can straighten that out,  My suspicion is that there is something wrong with the projects.  We have loads and loads of Grails 4 apps that have css and images in them and that definitely works in general.

Comment: I managed to resolve my issue by doing this instead: war {
    enabled = true
    archiveName "Wolf.war"
} I have an entangled SOF question here where I explained it a bit more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934349/compileassets-failing-on-upgrading-grails-application/61958494#61958494. So, I don't  quite understand if my project isn't set up right, or if there is a Grails/Gradle issue. But as of now I've got it working.